# Does electrum gives wallet.bin file or if it didn’t then how can I access wallet.bin file?

Tags: wallet, electrum, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat, dash

I have one electrum file which extension is .bin and I know the passphrase too but when I open that to electrum it don’t accept my passphrase but passphrase is correct 100% how I can excess that .bin file do anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Dash is off-topic in Bitcoin.stackexchange.com, See https://www.dash.org/forum/index.php?threads/how-convert-wallet-in-bin.49131/

Comment: Well file is encrypted through openssl  while I use enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -in success.bin -out success.txt  it gives error input reading data can I see encryption type ? Or any useful things